# conditionally render component angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a requirement to implement SSO login and external login using owin based authentication in my application. If the user is sso(single sign on) type user he will land on dashboard component and if not then he will land on login component.

For this i have make a request to my webapi from app component on ngInit event to get user Details (token, user access, group and role etc).

on the basis of webapi information i am navigating it either dashboard component or login component.

I am able to achieve my goal but its not as per my expectation because if user is SSO type he is able to navigate on dashboard but before it, he is also able to see login screen because its already in my route table in app.routingmodule.ts file.

I have two question where i need help-

1) what is the best way to render appropriate component as per my API Response?

2) What is the best way to manage user data(like as user details, permission, access_token) after succesfully login, should i use sessionStorage or something else?

my routing code as-

```
const fidsRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoardComponent }
  ];
```

my app component ngOnInit event as-

```
ngOnInit() {

this.authenticationservice.userLogin(this.loginData)
   .subscribe(
   res => {
     if (res.access_token != null) {
       this.userDetails = res;

       sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', this.userDetails.access_token);
       sessionStorage.setItem('userId', <any>this.userDetails.Id);
       //const session = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');

      // this.screenName = this.userDetails.Screen.split("~");
       //this.routeScreen = this.userDetails.Route.split("~");
       sessionStorage.setItem("UserId", <any>this.userDetails.Id);

       sessionStorage.setItem("MenuDataScreen", this.userDetails.Screen);

       sessionStorage.setItem("MenuDataRoute", this.userDetails.Route);

       this.router.navigate(['dashboardcomponent']);
     } 

     else {
       this.router.navigate(['logincomponent']);
     }
   },
   err => {
     this.router.navigate(['logincomponent']);
   }
   );
  }

}
```

Comment: this is what you need https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/

Comment: 1) router guards 2) check out ngrx [or simply use rxjs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 was answered in comments: Use route guards. I'd like to add the official guide: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

2) Storing a token in cookies, session- or localstorage is fine as long as the token has a reasonably short expiry time serverside. Don't persist any sensitive user data locally anywhere, it's not safe.

Comment: If its not safe then where can i persist sensitive data in angular 4 application?

Comment: I'd say any sensitive data (and any that can be used in any way to identify a user in a persisted manner, like a user id) In JS memory only. Just fetch the data again using the token if the user revisits while it's valid.

Comment: Tokens are safe (if implemented correctly on server) as they're unique every time, as long as they have a fairly short expiry.

Comment: I need to manage some user details like username and menu items as per role permissions, so where I can save these things because I don't want to load header items again and again. I need to manage these things on reload application as well. should i use NGRX Store?

Comment: NGRX doesn't persist anything either if the user reloads the app. I wouldn't worry about that because it's rare, no-one should need to force reload. And if they do, just reload the sensitive data using a token. Safest is to keep anything like a username only in memory - so ngrx or simply a service.

Comment: Second safest is probably session storage, but i wouldn't trust anything sensitive to that either.